# GTM Tag does't fire correct conditions

Tags: css, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to get a GTM tag fired for cta tracking but it somehow doesnt't work for some css classes. I already have several other tags in place and they all work well with the exact same settings. The gtm-settings are as indicated in the screenshots bellow. I also already tried with other settings such as RegEX and CSS selector but it all doesn't work.

CSS-Class of CTA-Button:

```
<a href="https://exampledomain.ch/kuenstler/" target="_self" class="button primary" style="border-radius:99px;padding:5 0px 0px 0px;">
<span>Alle entdecken</span>
```

Does anybody has an idea? Many thanks in advance!

[Screenshot variable settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFfGl.png)

[Screenshot tag settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRHbf.jpg)

[Screenshot trigger settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKZVe.png)

[Screenshot Debug Console Variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYqH1.png)

Comment: First, does the trigger fire or not? On that click, what is the value of your variable in the preview debugger. Finally, paste your html here, don't paste code as images.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately the tag doesn't fire at all. I don't exactly know to which specific value you refer to ,therefore I just added a screenshot of my debugging console for the respective variable.

Comment: I was referring to the variable that you've been using in your trigger. Because it didn't fire.  And it is indeed in your screenshot. See its value? Now we know why it doesn't fire. You need to change the trigger. In your code you didn't close the span, but that's fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your trigger filter to Matches CSS Selector. And this is the value of your selector: `a.button.primary, a.button.primary *`

Your problem is that click actually lands on a span in a rather than a itself, therefore, your click classes are empty. That span has no classes.

How do I know where the click lands? I can see that from the "value" of the Click Element variable in your debugger screenshot. That's not real value, but that's a generic selector that attempts to uniquely identify an element that was clicked on. The end of that selector. See how it actually has your a but then it has > span? There.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now everything works perfectly. I also had to change the filter element "click classes" to "click element".